# JavaScript issue changing class in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to copy a JavaScript script I saw elsewhere on the internet to allow my dropdown menu to open and close. It's quite simple logic really. Div class is set to xxx-closed and on click thanks to the JavaScript, it's supported to change the class to xxx-open but I've had no luck.

This is the script I've got on my site, it's just a small extract I'd taken from the original script.

```
(".collapsed header").bind("click",function(t) {

   t.preventDefault(),
   e(this).parent().toggleClass("opened","collapsed").find(".content")}),
   e(".foot-sw-cont").addClass("closed"),
   e(".foot-sw-cont").click(function(t)
  {
  t.preventDefault(),e(this).toggleClass("closed"),
  e(".foot-address").toggleClass("address-open"),
  e(".foot-extra").toggleClass("careers-open")}),
  e(".pagetop").click(function(t){
      t.preventDefault(),e("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},1e3)
})
```

I'm not sure if my mistake was simply missing out some code when I copied it as for the life of me I can't understand JavaScript! Because of that I'll copy a much larger block of it and paste that below so you can hopefully find my mistake.

```
.html(n)})}
e(".no-touch .award").hover(function(){

   e(this).find(".award-tooltip").addClass("shown")},
   function(){e(this).find(".award-tooltip").removeClass("shown")}),
   e(".touch .award").toggle(function(){

      e(".award-tooltip").removeClass("shown"),
      e(this).find(".award-tooltip").addClass("shown")},
      function(){
          e(this).find(".award-tooltip").removeClass("shown")}),

      e(".award-tooltip").click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()}),
      t<599&&(e("#y2007, #y2008, #y2009, #y2010, #y2011").addClass("closed"),

      e(".award-year").click(function(){

          var t=e(this).attr("data-year");
          e("#"+t).toggleClass("opened closed")})),
          e(".panel-item .content").parent().addClass("collapsed"),

          e(".collapsed header").bind("click",function(t) {

              t.preventDefault(),
              e(this).parent().toggleClass("opened","collapsed").find(".content")}),
              e(".foot-sw-cont").addClass("closed"),

          e(".foot-sw-cont").click(function(t){

              t.preventDefault(),e(this).toggleClass("closed"),
              e(".foot-address").toggleClass("address-open"),
              e(".foot-extra").toggleClass("careers-open")}),

          e(".pagetop").click(function(t){       

              t.preventDefault(),e("html,body").animate({scrollTop:0},1e3)}),
              e(".btn-blogcats").click(function(t){
              t.preventDefault(),
              e("#blog_cats").toggleClass("collapsed"),
              e(this).toggleClass("cats-opened")}),
              e("#map").length>0&&initialize(),

          e(".come-top").toggle(function(){

               e(this).parent().addClass("opened")},function(){
               e(this).parent().removeClass("opened")}),

          e(".img_links a").click(function(t){

              t.preventDefault();
              var n=e(this).attr("href"); 
              e("#imgholder").attr("src",n),
              e(".img_links a").removeClass("current"), 
              e(this).addClass("current")
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and css that goes with your javascript in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pBVpx/ Images etc don't load due to the css calling images locally but rest should work. Also, I'm aware the CSS is messy which is why I didn't post it here but yea, all there... Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly is the menu you want to open when you click on it ?

Comment: At the very bottom, the one that says "Contact".

Comment: I think you might want to decompose the problem to its base, keeping only the menu part in the page with related CSS and HTML, otherwise we have to diagnose a problem that is most probably not related to the menu itself, and therefore it makes this question useless for others trying to solve a menu problem

Comment: Even if I was to keep just the relative CSS and HTML I would still need help. The issue here is not with the CSS / HTML but with the javascript code I believe...

Comment: In Chrome browser, hit F12 (or developers options) in the options menu (upper right icon) and check in the console tab if you find any error related to your JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult to debug compressed JavaScript, but if I had to guess I would bet that `.collapsed header` either never exists or does not exist at the time `.bind` is called.

```
$(document).on("click", ".collapsed header", function (t) {
```

This will delegate the `click` event so it will affect `.collapsed header` even if they are added to the DOM after `.on` is called.  You could also try wrapping everything in `$(document).ready`

Comment: Hmm thanks but still no luck with that code... Like I said I dont have the slightest idea about javascript so I don't understand what you mean by wrapping everything in document ready.. Do you simply mean doing $(document).ready{ ALL the code }? and if so, how will that help?

Comment: Actually, that would be $(document).ready(function () { // your statements goes here });

Comment: @BradAndrews if `$(document).on` does not work then I would not expect `$(document).ready` to either.  Do you get any JavaScript errors?

Comment: No nothing shows on screen with the code I'm using however when I click the item that's supposed to dropdown it simply takes me to the top of the page...

Comment: @BradAndrews definitely sounds like a JavaScript error to me.  Check the console.

Comment: What console would that be? As I said earlier, please treat me like an absolute noob when referring to JavaScript. I've been learning it but I think it's quite clear that I've been failing.